# How can I find out when a person started talking?And preferably when he finished speakingю JavaScript. Without Speech Recognition API

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, voice

How can I find out when a person started talking? And preferably when he finished speaking. JavaScript. Without Speech Recognition API. Because SpeechRecognition available only in latest Google Chrome. And it's an exp.technol.

Comment: you could monitor the levels on the audio input, after the user has allowed you to monitor their microphone, of course ... and what is `an exp.technol.`?

Comment: How can i monitor the levels on the audio input? exp.technol it stands experimental technology.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Comment: Thanks for answer. But what if the user has a sensitive microphone? I need the script to give a signal that the user has started talking. And not when he presses the keyboard or sneezes

Comment: then adjust your code to know the difference

Comment: @ВитязиTeam If you don't want to wait for speech recognition to become available through an API, you can of course implement it yourself. But [speech recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition) is a vast field, so it will take a lot of effort.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for answer) Just need to deploy project in production, it turned out that the speechend events do not work correctly in the Speech Recognition API) Namely, speechend is triggered after almost 10 seconds. Even if I finished talking a long time ago)